# MVC - public list inside the model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC, starting a new project and would like to ask before i proceed on before its to late to change or its more hassle to change.

Can i add my list inside the model? currently i have my code like this:
or should i put my list in another folder perhaps Service? im not sure.

Models/Filters/ObjAdmissionsRegion.cs

```
namespace EC.Dashboard.Models.Filters
{
    public class ObjAdmissionsRegion
    {
        public string ArgName { get; set; }
        public int ArgPk { get; set; }

        public List<ObjAdmissionsRegion> GetAdmissionsRegion()
        {
            List<ObjAdmissionsRegion> list = new List<ObjAdmissionsRegion>();

            DalAdmissionsRegion dal = new DalAdmissionsRegion();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dal.GetAdmissionsRegion().Rows)
            {
                ObjAdmissionsRegion obj = new ObjAdmissionsRegion();
                obj.ArgName = (string)dr["ARG_NAME"];
                obj.ArgPk = (int)dr["ARG_PK"];
                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

DataLayer/DalAdmissionsRegion.cs

```
namespace EC.Dashboard.DataLayer.Filters
{
    public class DalAdmissionsRegion
    {
        public DataTable GetAdmissionsRegion()
        {
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.Append("select ARG_PK, ARG_NAME from dbo.TBL_ADMISSIONS_REGION_ARG where ARG_DELETED = 0 order by ARG_NAME");

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strBuilder.ToString(), ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ecProd"].ConnectionString))
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller/FiltersController.cs

```
namespace EC.Dashboard.Controllers
{
    public class FiltersController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult ReadAdmissionsRegion()
        {
            Models.Filters.ObjAdmissionsRegion mod = new Models.Filters.ObjAdmissionsRegion();
            return Json(mod.GetAdmissionsRegion(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you - Yes. Should you - No! You have made you app impossible to unit test. Put the code to generate the collection in a separate service (and then use DI to inject the service into the controller)

Answer (score 0):

as long as the data in the database is expendable you can just clear that and add the list.

using the entity framework, codefirst wil just generate a new database with the new list added.